# Making a random quiz in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, random, submit

So I'm trying to make a `quiz.html` file which will prompt the user for the no. of questions they want to answer. Based on their input, the random questions will be generated. So I understand it's gonna have to be a loop that will loop till the no. input into the alert box.
So my scoreMe() function apparently isn't giving any answer. I'm trying to check if the checked radio button for a particular question is equal to the correct answer but I'm just getting my score as 0%. So can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
        <div id="quesRes"></div>
<script>

    var quizObj = [
    { 
        "question": "What is the capital of Bangladesh?",
        "choice": ["Dhaka", "Chittagong", "Sylhet"],
        "correct": ["Dhaka"]
   },
   { 
        "question": "What does 2+2 equal to?",
        "choice": ["3", "2", "4"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["4"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the real name of Damon Salvatore?",
        "choice": ["Paul Wesley", "Steven McQueen", "Ian Somerhalder"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Ian Somerhalder"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the name of the largest planet in the universe?",
        "choice": ["Earth", "Jupiter", "Uranus"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Jupiter"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the capital of New York?",
        "choice": ["Manhattan", "NYC", "Albany"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Albany"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "How many bones does the human body have?",
        "choice": ["109", "206", "114"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["206"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the alter ego of Batman?",
        "choice": ["Bruce Banner", "Bruce Wayne", "Tony Stark"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Bruce Wayne"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "How many books are there in the Harry Potter series?",
        "choice": ["7", "5", "8"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["7"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is Naruto's surname?",
        "choice": ["Sarutobi", "Uchiha", "Uzumaki"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Uzumaki"]
   },
    { 
        "question": "What is the name of Sherlock Holmes' partner?",
        "choice": ["Peterson", "Watson", "Hanson"],  //quizObj[2].choice[0],quizObj[2].choice[1]
        "correct": ["Watson"]
   },

];

  var track = [];

    var maxQues = prompt("How many questions do you want to answer?", "5");
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxQues);

    var str='<h4>Answer all the questions</h4>';

    for(var i=0;i<maxQues;i++){

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxQues);
        str+=(i+1)+'.  '+quizObj[rand].question+'<br>';
        str+='<form><table>'+
            '<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a2"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[1]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a3"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[2]+'</td></tr>'+
        '</table></form><br>';
    track[i]=rand;
    }
    str += '<input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="scoreMe()"><br><br>';
    str += 'Score: <input id="score" type="text" size="8" ><br><br><br>';
    document.getElementById('quesRes').innerHTML = str;

  function scoreMe(){
    var sum=0;
    for(var j=0;j<maxQues;j++){
      for(var k=0;k<3;k++){
        if(quizObj[track[j]].choice[k].checked===quizObj[track[j]].correct[0]){
          console.log('Works'+j);
          sum++;
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('score').value = ((sum/maxQues)*100)+'%';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @BlackPOP: Please pay attention when reviewing edits. The edit from `quiz.html` to `quiz. HTML` really isn't valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your radio buttons have the same name, hence belong to the same group.
Give them different names and you should be fine:

```
str+='<table>'+
            '<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a2"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[1]+'</td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td id="a3"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '"/>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[2]+'</td></tr>'+
        '</table><br>';
```

[Quoting MDN on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

> Radio buttons that have the same value for the name attribute are in the same "radio button group"; only one radio button in a group can be selected at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

```
'<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" name="radio" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'
```

With:

```
'<tr><td id="a1"><input type="radio" name="radio' + i + '" />'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+quizObj[rand].choice[0]+'</td></tr>'
//                                            There ^
```

This way, the "names" of the inputs (which are used to "group" them), have the question's ID in them.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "string " as an answer to your questions , add index number .. it will solve the problem

```
var quizObj = [
{ 
    "question": "What is the capital of Bangladesh?",
    "choice": ["Dhaka", "Chittagong", "Sylhet"],
    "correct": 0
```